# Why setting U and V channels to 0 leads to displaying a Blue picture?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

**What I did:**

- I read a BGR image and convert it to YUV color space.
- Then I set its U and V channels to 0
- I display the image and I see it is all blue (as if I set R and B to 0, instead)

**Questions:**

- Why setting U and V values to 0 leads the the G and R channels of the picture set to 0 also ?
- Why the image is displayed in blue (BGR color space) instead of YUV color space ?

**Code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread('rgb_pic.png')
yuv_img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)
cv2.imwrite('yuv_pic',yuv_img)

cv2.namedWindow('YUV',cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv2.imshow('YUV',yuv_img) # Displayed image is YUV, that is ok
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

im=yuv_img # Copy the YUV image to an other one
for in in range(im.shape[0]):
    for j in range(im.shape[1]):
       im[i,j,1]=0 # Set U to 0
       im[i,j,2]=0 # Set V to 0
 
# Display im
cv2.namedWindow('Result',cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv2.imshow('Result',im) # Displayed image is totally BLUE :(
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Results:**

`yuv_img` displayed like this (that is normal result, what I expect):

[image]

`im` displayed like this (I do not understand why it is blue):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `imshow` waits input images in BGR format (OpenCV assumes the first channel (now Y) as Blue). Well, you set the second and third channel to zero => only the first channel will contain non-zero elements so only the blue channel takes part in the visualization.